# Improve speed of a File System storing hundreds of different formats

Tags: python, file

I am writing a file system for a Laboratory Quality Control System, where hundreds of different machines are sending information that needs to be collected at a central location. The format of each message maybe different, and new formats may be introduced at any time.

Specification:

1. Written in Python
2. A File of records with:
   variable no of fields
   variable length fields
   variable type fields (string, integer, float)
3. To return a List:
   where the first element is the record-type (or ID)
   followed by each field

I WOULD LIKE TO IMPROVE TO SPEED OF THE READ (Get) PROCEDURE

```
def Get():
    L =[]
    try:
        nos = ord(f.read(1))           # read no of fields
    except:
        return []                      # end of record
    for i in range(nos):
        try: 
            x = f.read(1)              # read field lengt
            y = f.read(ord(x))         # read field
            try:
                L.append(int(y))       # apend ifinteger
            except:
                try:
                    L.append(float(y)) # append if float    
                except:
                    L.append(y)        # append if string        
        except:
            pass
    return L
#----------------------------------------------------
def Put(*x):
    f.write(chr(len(x)))         # write no of fields
    for i in range(len(x)):      # for each field
        y = str(x[i])                 # get field length
        f.write(chr(len(y)))          # write field length
        f.write(y)                    # write field
#----------------------------------------------------
f = open('x', 'w')
Put(1,'aaaaaaaa', 1, -1, 1.1, -1.1)
Put(2,'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 2, -2, 2.2, -2.2, 'abc', 12)   
f.close()
#----------------------------------------------------
f = open('x', 'r')
while True:
    LL = Get()
    if LL != []:
        print(LL)
        for i in range(len(LL)):
            print(type(LL[i]))
    else:
        break  
f.close()
```

Comment: One rule of thumb to save your hair: Don't use bare `try/except` Specify the exceptions you can deal with in the `except` clause.

Comment: The core problem is your file format is very inefficient (i.e. time-consuming)  for reading and writing.  Are you limited to using this format?

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**

- You principally care about functionality
- You are not restricted to your posted file format

Then ~7X faster performance in both reading and writing can be made using pickle for serialization/deserialization as follows.

**Original Code (with corrections)**

```
# Corrections:
#   1. Fixed Bare try/except issue
#   2. Filehandle should be passed into the functions rather than using a global
def Get(f):
    L =[]
    try:
        nos = ord(f.read(1))           # read no of fields
    except ValueError:
        return []                      # end of record
    for i in range(nos):
        try: 
            x = f.read(1)              # read field lengt
            y = f.read(ord(x))         # read field
            try:
                L.append(int(y))       # apend ifinteger
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    L.append(float(y)) # append if float    
                except ValueError:
                    L.append(y)        # append if string        
        except ValueError:
            pass     # error reading file or with ord conversion
    return L
#----------------------------------------------------
def Put(f, *x):
    f.write(chr(len(x)))         # write no of fields
    for i in range(len(x)):      # for each field
        y = str(x[i])                 # get field length
        f.write(chr(len(y)))          # write field length
        f.write(y)
```

**Pickle Version (faster)**

```
import pickle

def Get_pickle(f):
    try:
        return pickle.load(f)
    except EOFError:
        return None
#----------------------------------------------------
def Put_pickle(f, *x):
    pickle.dump(x, f)
```

**Usage Pickle Version**

```
with open('x.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    Put_pickle(1,'aaaaaaaa', 1, -1, 1.1, -1.1)
    Put_pickle(2,'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 2, -2, 2.2, -2.2, 'abc', 12)   
#----------------------------------------------------
with open('x.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        LL = Get_pickle()
        if LL:
            print(LL)
            for i in range(len(LL)):
                print(type(LL[i]))
        else:
            break
```

Output (same output as original)

```
(1, 'aaaaaaaa', 1, -1, 1.1, -1.1)
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
(2, 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 2, -2, 2.2, -2.2, 'abc', 12)
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
```

**Timing Test**

```
n = 100000 # number of repeats of posted data
```

Time Original

```
def test_write():
    with open('x.txt', 'w') as f:
        for _ in range(n):
            Put(f, 1,'aaaaaaaa', 1, -1, 1.1, -1.1)
            Put(f, 2,'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 2, -2, 2.2, -2.2, 'abc', 12)  
            
def test_get():
    with open('x.txt', 'r') as f:
        while Get(f):
            pass
            
%timeit test_write() # Output: 3.45 s ± 244 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit test_get()   # Output: 4.3 s ± 97.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Time Pickle Version

```
import timeit

def test_write_pickle():
    with open('x.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        for _ in range(n):
            Put_pickle(f, 1,'aaaaaaaa', 1, -1, 1.1, -1.1)
            Put_pickle(f, 2,'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 2, -2, 2.2, -2.2, 'abc', 12)   
            
def test_get_pickle():
    with open('x.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        while Get_pickle(f):
            pass

%timeit test_write_pickle() # Output: 474 ms ± 57.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit test_get_pickle()    # Output: 562 ms ± 82.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and detailed solution. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I am not familiar with pickle. The amount of data received is far in excess of available memory. Can pickle files be appended to ?

Comment: Also, the file will be almost twice as big...

Comment: I made some comparisons with 1,000,000 records: The pickle method is approx 10 times faster, and the file it creates is 116Mb, and the original method filesize is 65Mb

Comment: @user1530405 -- yes, you can append to pickle files.

Comment: @user1530405 -- regarding the pickle files being 2X larger--this shouldn't be an issue since both files are on disk rather than in internal memory.  I assume this space is not an issue.

Comment: @user1530405 - regarding appending to the file: Found this to be much slower.  Perhaps if you describe the use case I can help with a better solution.

Comment: The Client is very security conscious, so I was given only the info that is necessary for my part of the job to create the file. They have currently 350 machines, each sending 12 messages per minute. Each message is approx. 20 bytes. Most of the info is float, such as temperature, humidity, viscosity, color, time, size, etc. The Client envisages that eventually will have close to 1,000 machines operating. So we are talking about many terabytes of data. I have no clue as to how they plan to access the file, I was only asked to create it, others will write the code to access it.

Comment: @user1530405 -- with that much data and volume perhaps a NoSQL database would be better than a flat-file.   Check out [A Comparative Study of Databases
for Storing Sensor Data](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1325707/FULLTEXT01.pdf)

Comment: Now that I (finally) received information about the volume and throughput of incoming data, it seems that the speed of creating and accessing the file is less important than storage size. Any NoSQL system would affect the filesize adversely.  Thanks again for your help. PS. But you were right, Pickle is definitely the fastest way to read and write to disk (in python)

Comment: @user1530405 -- if the file size is what's important then compressing the sensor data would be relevant.  But, this depends upon the data.  For instance, if it's a collection of sensors that are sampled periodically, then compression would be based upon compressing the data stream from each sensor.